# Is there any way to trigger a Google Cloud build ONLY when a merge request is accepted on a specific branch?

Tags: github, google-apps-script, build, google-cloud-platform, triggers

Basically I just started using Google Cloud and I'm looking for a way to trigger a deployment ONLY when a pull request is accepted on a distant github repository.

I'm currently using the google "Cloud Build Trigger" to execute my 'cloudbuild.yaml' as soon as a push is detected on my master branch, but simply attempting a merge request seems to trigger my build process.

This is troublesome as a merge request will be reviewed by peers and I don't want my cloud application to rebuild if the merge request is to be denied after being reviewed.

[image: Screen capture of my cloudbuild.yaml]
[image: Screen capture of my cloud build trigger]

As this feature is still in beta, I assume this is not supported yet and that there is a better way to handle such task, but when I heard of the trigger feature it seemed like the most straightforward way to connect my github repository to the build process on google cloud. Anyway, hope someone had to face this issue or can help me figure this one out.

Thanks !

Comment: That sounds not normal. Did you open an issue ?

Comment: Actually, testing the same feature today seems to work as expected (only when the merge request is accepted). I'll do more testing to figure out what went wrong the first time.

Comment: If this FR is implemented you could simply check if the _PR_NUMBER substitution exists: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236014017

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds), Cloud Build triggers currently only support changes pushed to the build source (a remote Github repo in this case). There doesn't seem to be a way to distinguish between a merge resulting from a (remote) pull request or a local one from the Google Cloud Console GUI.

However, you are not without options. One alternative is to leverage Github's [PullRequestEvent Webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent) and deploy a GAS Web App or Cloud Function to serve as a web-hook endpoint. The GAS Web App or Cloud Function could then parse the event payload for GitHub's `PullRequestEvent` and if the pull request is `closed` and `merged` then you call the [REST API for the Cloud Build service](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/) to start your build.